# Computing expected time complexity of recursive program

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I wish to determine the average processing time T(n) of the recursive algorithm:

```
int myTest( int n ) {
  if ( n <= 0 ) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    int i = random( n - 1 );
    return myTest( i ) + myTest( n - 1 - i );
  }
}
```

provided that the algorithm random( int n ) spends one time unit to return
a random integer value uniformly distributed in the range [0, n] whereas
all other instructions spend a negligibly small time (e.g., T(0) = 0).

This is certainly not of the simpler form T(n) = a * T(n/b) + c so I am lost at how to write it. I can't figure out how to write it due to the fact that I am taking a random number each time from 0 to n-1 range and supplying it twice to the function and asking for the sum of those two calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relations are:

```
T(0) = 0
T(n) = 1 + sum(T(i) + T(n-1-i) for i = 0..n-1) / n
```

The second can be simplified to:

```
T(n) = 1 + 2*sum(T(i) for i = 0..n-1) / n
```

Multiplying by n:

```
n T(n) = n + 2*sum(T(i) for i = 0..n-1)
```

Noting that `(n-1) T(n-1) = n-1 + 2*sum(T(i) for i = 0..n-2)`, we get:

```
n T(n) = (n-1) T(n-1) + 1 + 2T(n-1)
       = (n+1) T(n-1) + 1
```

Or:

```
T(n) = ((n+1)T(n-1) + 1) / n
```

This has the solution T(n) = n, which you can derive by telescoping the series, or by guessing the solution and then substituting it in to prove it works.

Comment: From the specification I am sure that `T(0)` exists. But when you move from step 1 to step 2 you assume that for `i > 0`, the value `T(i)` exists. How do we prove this ? Because if it is infinite the following steps of the proof are not funded.

Comment: @fjardon there's no infinity -- the code is written so that recursive calls are always on a smaller input which bounds the height of the call stack. That is, if `myTest(n)` calls `myTest(i)`, then 0 <= `i` < `n`.

Comment: @Paul could you explain how we got to this step? n T(n) = (n-1) T(n-1) + 1 + 2T(n-1) = (n+1) T(n-1) + 1. I don't understand this.

Comment: The omitted step is to rearrange nT(n) like this: nT(n) = n + 2sum(T(i) for i = 0..n-1) = n-1 + 2sum(T(i) for i = 0..n-2) + 1 + 2T(n-1). Then note that n-1 + 2sum(T(i) for i = 0..n-2) is (n-1)T(n-1).

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for clarification.